# Socket data from Node.js is not received in the Flash client

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, node.js

I'm having a problem to receive data from `socket.io` to Flash (actionscript).

I've tried:

**Server (nodejs) socket.io :**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(9000);
setInterval(function() {
io.sockets.emit('hello');
console.log("test");
}, 500 );
```

**Client (actionscript) Socket();**

```
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.events.*;
var socket:Socket = new Socket();
Security.allowDomain("*");
socket.connect("localhost", 9000);
socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
function onConnect( evt:Event ):void
{
trace( "Connected to flash");
}
function socketDataHandler(evt:ProgressEvent):void  
{  
trace("socketDataHandler: " + evt);
}
```

**Output**

Flash connects succesful to the server and trace "Connected to flash" but it cannot receive data. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://wellconsidered.be/post/10519721421/socket-policy-file-for-as3-with-node-js-socket-server An article writing by Pieter Michels.

Comment: Please have a look this tutorial which help me:
<a>http://www.rivellomultimediaconsulting.com/node-js-for-flash-and-flex-introduction/</a>

Answer (score 0):

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#includeExamplesSummary and look at the method called `readResponse`.

You need to read the bytes from the stream.

Or just use that very example and you'll know that there is not something wrong with the client-side functionality.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is still. flash can't read data from socket.io, I think the probleme in server code. can anyone correct the server code ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the server-side, since looks correct to me, maybe you should test it with normal JS client first to ensure.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think that will work, because socket.io has it's own protocol which uses several transport methods such as websocket. But your action script is just having a normal flash socket I believe. The best is that you use the normal socket.io javascript client and and use a messaging system to communicate with your action script client. In this case, I think [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html) link is useful for you, in which describes this messaging.

Update:

These libraries may be what you are looking for:
https://github.com/ascorbic/socket-io-actionscript
https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO

Comment: socket.io can commnicate whit actionscript :)

Comment: When I run the example the client connect succesful to the server but it's can't receive data. :)

Comment: well it can connect, because it uses web sockets, but it cannot communicate with socket.io protocol which is built on the transport methods such as web sockets. Anyway I did a search and updated my answer.

Comment: I run the code in flash as3 and I received this errors :
1172: Could not find the definition mx.utils. mx.core. mx.events. :(